# Modeling evolution of continuous mean-field model?

Tags: complex-systems, models, mean-field-theory

Suppose $f(i,t)$ indicates state $i$ at time $t$. Are there examples of exactly solvable models where $f$ is described by differential equations similar to one below?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(i,t) = -2 f(i,t)d(i) + u(i) \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} i\, v(i) f(i,t).$$

It feels like solving this needs a continuous version of Sherman-Morrison formula which I wasn't able to locate, so I'm looking to learn how to analyze this kind of system.

Specific case I'm looking at has $f(i,0)=1$, $d(i)=u(i)=v(i)=\frac{1}{3}(1+i)^{-2}$, and I need to solve for $g(t)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ f(i, t)$

Motivation: it's the continuous version of bird population dynamics model described [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848).
Cross-posted on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4686487/)